# SSRS error NT Authority\Anonymous Logon failed for new client machine

Tags: sql, amazon-ec2, reporting-services, ssrs-2016

I’m in a situation that we have sql server and ssrs in one ad domain and the machines accessing the ssrs (client) is in a different ad domain. The login process is impersonated and user login as anonymous user. Both ad domains have trust setup and system works perfectly fine for years. Now we have added a new machine in the environment from where the report server is accessed. The new machine opens report server web page and i can see all the available reports i can run but when i run a report im getting attached error message. The topology is called double hop. Any ideas how we can fix it.

Important: existing client machines are still working fine.

Ssrs logs r also throwning same error.

New and existing env difference: existing client is on-prem jump box. The new client machine is in AWS connecting to sql and ssrs on-prem. both domain controllers, client machine and sql and reporting server is also in aws, different vpcs.
Existing machine is os server 2012 where new one is 2019.

Any ideas…

Checked connectivity for new client flow logs doesnt show any traffic being blocked towards domain controllers.
Both domain controllers accept tcp and udp 88 other than all required ports.